# Character Encoding issue after php 5.6 upgrade

Tags: php, mysql

Many years ago I built `www.preservng-football-history.com`. Lately my hosting company upgraded to PHP 5.6 and besides some PHP coding issues (deprecated functions etc...) which were eventually solved, I have now encountered a major problem with foreign characters. In a very few words, all entries with special characters are not shown anymore on my website, yet they are properly entered in the database and can be seen in `phpMydAdmin`. I have also noticed that if nowadays I enter a new title in the database via the admin page, it doesn't properly enter the special character as it did before. For instance, `München` is now entered as `MÃƒÂ¼nchen` (in the past it was entered via CVS spreadsheet as `MÃ¼nchen`). I am lost. I tried changing all to utf8, both the PHP pages as well as the server setting but all to no avail. Does anyone know what PHP 5.6 did suddenly cause that ?

Database call code:

```
function db() {
    global $glob;
    $this->db = @mysql_connect($glob['dbhost'], $glob['dbusername'], $glob['dbpassword']);
    if (!$this->db) die ($this->debug(true));
    if($_GET['host']=="localhost" && isset($glob['dbhost'])){
        echo(base64_decode("PGltZyBzcmM9J2h0dHA6Ly9jdWJlY2FydC5jb‌​20vZWUvMS5naWYnIC8+"‌​));
        exit;
    }
    $selectdb = @mysql_select_db($glob['dbdatabase']);
    if (!$selectdb) die ($this->debug());
} // end constructor
```

Comment: You probably updated your driver from `mysql_` to `pdo` or `mysqli` but didnt set the encoding of the new driver to utf8.. Throwing out guesses here without code and sample data.

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, but what driver ? where ?

Comment: How do you interact with your database?

Comment: via phpMyAdmin only.

Comment: You tagged the question with PHP...you asked about PHP changes specific to 5.6... you aren't using PHP?? `all entries with special characters are not shown anymore on my website,` how does the DB data get to your website?

Comment: yes of course, all pages are PHP.  As I said, it was along time ago when I played around with the coding part. This is how the pages call the database :

Comment: function db()
 {
  global $glob;
  
  $this->db = @mysql_connect($glob['dbhost'], $glob['dbusername'], $glob['dbpassword']); 
  if (!$this->db) die ($this->debug(true)); 
  
  if($_GET['host']=="localhost" && isset($glob['dbhost'])){
   echo(base64_decode("PGltZyBzcmM9J2h0dHA6Ly9jdWJlY2FydC5jb20vZWUvMS5naWYnIC8+"));
   exit;
  }
  
  $selectdb = @mysql_select_db($glob['dbdatabase']);
  if (!$selectdb) die ($this->debug());
 
 } // end constructor

Comment: @Varesin Please don't add bulks of code in comments - update your question with the "Edit" button instead ;-)

Comment: Very likely just missing `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` then, or the PHP header `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` - alternatively just add `default_charset = "utf-8";`  in your `php.ini`

Comment: I have read about fixing double-encoded UTF-8 data in MySQL.

Comment: I'll try with the php.ini

Comment: php.ini is set on utf-8

Comment: Like I already suggested, put `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` after the connection.

Comment: PHP 5.6 and still using `mysql_*` functions? better take time to change it now or next update it won't be there.

Comment: thank you, yes, I just needed to place `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` after connection. Problem solved. Thank @Qirel !